# JMX and Debugging on Tomcat inside Docker

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, jmx, remote-debugging

I am trying to setup IntelliJ to connect to a Tomcat instance running in a Docker container. I would like to be able to use remote debugging and also deploy remotely using JMX.

I can enable remote debugging using the environment variables

```
JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

and by starting Tomcat with `catalina.sh jpda run`, so remote debugging works without a problem.

I can also do this alternatively with

```
CATALINA_OPTS='-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,suspend=n,server=y'
```

and then I don't need to use `catalina.sh jpda run`

No matter what I do, I cannot get JMX to work. I verified that I have `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` in /usr/local/tomcat/lib`.

I have tried setting `CATALINA_OPTS` and `JAVA_OPTS` to

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.99.100
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I have verified that `192.168.99.100` is the IP of my docker machine. I have tried connecting to JMX with VisualJM and IntelliJ, it does not work. I have verified that the port `1099` is open and available from the host.

Tomcat is receiving the JMX args

```
20-Apr-2016 23:50:14.019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099 -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.99.100 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

Why can't I get JMX to work? There is no information available in any logs and this will not work no matter what I try.

Edit: `lsof -i :1099` shows nothing running on that port

I am running on Mac OS X. It is a docker-machine but I believe docker uses virualbox on mac because it can't run containers natively.
 I have mapped the port. `docker ps` shows `0.0.0.0:1099->1099/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp`. Ports `8080` and `8000` work so 1099 should be mapped correctly too.

Comment: If you ssh onto the docker container and run `hostname -i ` (assuming that's possible in your container), what is the result?

Comment: @EngineerDollery The result is `172.17.0.3` but I assumed that I was supposed to use the IP of the machine not the container. When I ping `192.168.99.100` (the IP of the docker machine), I get a response. When I ping `172.17.0.3`, 100% packet loss

Comment: Have you read this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31257968/how-to-access-jmx-interface-in-docker-from-outside or this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958421/access-tomcat-running-in-docker-container-by-jmx

Comment: @EngineerDollery I have. My situation is different. I am trying to access the docker JMX from the same machine the container is running on. As you can see from my edit, I see nothing running on port 1099 on the docker container so it looks like JMX isn't even running but I see no logs to find a reason why.

Comment: Have you mapped the port to your host? What OS is your host? Are you using virtualbox or docker-machine?

Comment: @EngineerDollery I have appended my answer to the question. Also, I think this is irrelevant considering that in the docker container, there are no processes operating on 1099.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? I think this may be related to using the `catalina-jmx-remote.jar` and the `JmxRemoteLifecycleListener` together with the `com.sun.management.jmxremote.*` system properties. From my understanding the `JmxRemoteLifecycleListener` replaces the port system properties (see [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/listeners.html#JMX_Remote_Lifecycle_Listener_-_org.apache.catalina.mbeans.JmxRemoteLifecycleListener)). Not sure how/if it's is supposed to work of you specifiy both...

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35466461/how-to-connect-with-jmx-from-host-to-docker-container-in-docker-machine/37896841#37896841) for a working setup without the `JmxRemoteLifecycleListener`. Otherwise could you add the configuration of the `JmxRemoteLifecycleListener` to your question as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to connect when I used 0.0.0.0 for jmxremote.host and server.hostname

```
 HOST=0.0.0.0
    java -Xmn100M  -XX:+PrintGCDetails  -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=40 -Xmx384M $JAVA_OPTS\
     -Dcom.sun.management.config.file=/opt/app/management.properties \
     -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/app/logging.properties \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=$JMX_PORT \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=$JMX_PORT \
     -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.host=$HOST \
     -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=$HOST \
     -jar /opt/app/app.jar
```

Comment: Finally! I wish I have found it earlier and not after spending my entire day trying to make darn thing work. Thanks so much.